# Pulling Top results in Pandas Given Parameters

Tags: pandas

I am trying to pull the top results in a pandas data frame given a list of parameters in another pandas data frame. I am not sure how to go about doing this. I have the following data frames. I would like to link my symbols in df1 with df2 that match in Years and have lowest price. I do not want to go over the amount to buy in df1. So as an example, I would like to buy all of x1 and 75000 of x2 to fulfill my X order in df1. I would like to create a list of all symbols in df2 that will fulfill the orders in df1. Any suggestions?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol':list('XYZ'),'Amount to buy':[125000,200000,50000],'Years':[5,7,3]})

Symbol  Amount to Buy    Years
X      125000               5
Y      200000               7
Z      50000                3



df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol':'X1,X2,Y1,Y2,Z1,Z2'.split(','),'Amount Offered':[50000,100000,165000,110000,85000,90000],'Years':[5,5,7,7,3,3],'Price':'$5,$6,$3,$5,$7,$10'.split(',')})

Symbol   Amount Offered  Years  Price
  X1            50000       5    $5
  X2           100000       5    $6
  Y1           165000       7    $3
  Y2           110000       7    $5
  Z1           85000        3    $7
  Z2            90000       3    $10


for Amount_Offered in df2.iterrows():
    if Amount_Offered < x_buy:
        print ('buy this')



ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
 a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Edit: so far I have set my X amounnt to buy as a variable, x_buy

Comment: could you provide a sample of output (resultant) dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try first to separate the letter from the number this way:

```
>>> df_new = df2['Symbol'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(re.split('(\d*)',x)[:2]))

>>> df_new.columns=['Symbol', 'Symbol_i']   

>>> df_new

  Symbol Symbol_i
0      X        1
1      X        2
2      Y        1
3      Y        2
4      Z        1
5      Z        2
```

And then you can create a new df2 with the new symbols:

```
>>> df2_new = pd.concat([df_new, df2.iloc[:,1:]],axis=1)

>>> df2_new
  Symbol Symbol_i  Amount Offered  Years Price
0      X        1           50000      5    $5
1      X        2          100000      5    $6
2      Y        1          165000      7    $3
3      Y        2          110000      7    $5
4      Z        1           85000      3    $7
5      Z        2           90000      3   $10
```

Then you can merge df1 and df2_new on symbol:

```
>>> df_merged = df1.merge(df2_new,on=['Symbol'])
>>> df_merged

  Symbol  Amount to Buy  Years_x Symbol_i  Amount Offered  Years_y Price
0      X         125000        5        1           50000        5    $5
1      X         125000        5        2          100000        5    $6
2      Y         200000        7        1          165000        7    $3
3      Y         200000        7        2          110000        7    $5
4      Z          50000        3        1           85000        3    $7
5      Z          50000        3        2           90000        3   $10
```

And then try to loop per symbol and subtract each buy

```
df_total = pd.DataFrame()
for s in df_merged['Symbol'].unique():
    df_temp = df2_new[df_new['Symbol']==s]
    available = df1[df1['Symbol']==s]['Amount to Buy'].values[0] 
    for index, row in df_temp.iterrows():
        row['Amount bought'] = row['Amount Offered'] if row['Amount Offered'] < available else available
        available -= row['Amount Offered']
        df_total = pd.concat([df_total,row.to_frame().T],axis=0)

df_total['Amount bought'][df_total['Amount bought']<0]=0
```

Then df_total will result in:

```
>>> df_total

      Symbol Symbol_i Amount Offered Years Price Amount bought
    0      X        1          50000     5    $5         50000
    1      X        2         100000     5    $6         75000
    2      Y        1         165000     7    $3        165000
    3      Y        2         110000     7    $5         35000
    4      Z        1          85000     3    $7         50000
    5      0        0              0     0     0             0
```

Comment: If you are ok with the answer, please mark it as valid with the green tick so this issue is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of your question I think the code below will give you the result you are looking for - but, I must warn you, while it works, it's a pretty ugly solution.

```
df = pd.Series()

for df1_i, df1_row in df1.iterrows():
    symbol = df1_row['Symbol']
    remaining = df1_row['Amount to Buy']

    for df2_i, df2_row in df2.iterrows():
        if remaining > 0:
            if symbol in df2_row['Symbol']:
                remaining -= df2_row['Amount Offered']
                df = df.set_value(df2_i, df2_row['Symbol'])
```

Running the data you provided through this code will result in a `Series` that looks like:

```
0  X1
1  X2
2  Y1
3  Y2
4  Z1
```